# Separable topological spaces. Origin of terminology.

Tags: general-topology, terminology, separable-spaces

Several terminologies in topology have as background an analogy. Let me illustrate these analogies with two examples.

- For example, it is easy to accept the terminology ['reflective space'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_space#Reflexive_Banach_spaces) for Banach's space $X$ whose bidual $X^{\ast\ast}$ is an exact copy of $X$.That is, it makes sense to look at the bidual space $X^{\ast\ast}$ as an image reflected from the original space $X$ by the canonical application $J:X\to X^{\ast\ast}$. Here, $J(x): X^\ast\to \mathbb{R}$ is the aplicaticon $J(x)(f)=f(x)$.
- Another example. Let an $X$ set be equipped as two topologies. We say that the topology $\tau_1$ is thinner than the $\tau_2$ topology if we have $\tau_2\subset \tau_1$. This means that the topology $\tau_1$ has more open than the $\tau_2$ topology. We know that the more open a topology has the harder it is to find convergent sequences in the topology. If we imagine topology as a "sieve" that lets only the convergent sequences pass, the thinner the topology, the fewer the sequences will converge.

In mathematics, a topological space is called separable if it contains a countable and dense subset.

> **QUESTION.** What is the analogy behind the terminology "separable" to designate topological spaces that contain a subset that is both countable and dense?

I have done several researches to know the reason for this terminology in several books such as  [General topology](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0800202090)  (by Ryszard Engelking),  [Topology: a first course](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0139254951) (by James R. Munkres) and [General topology](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486815447) (by  John L. Kelley) but I did not succeed.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/51494/why-the-name-separable-space

Comment: @RobertThingum The answers to this question in the mathoverflow you posted, while very interesting, just say that the term 'separable' was coined by M. Fréchet and did not provide an answer to my question.

Comment: I suppose some explanation would have been nice. I was intending to direct you to the page in general, not just the answer.  In the comments you will see the illustrative example of the rational numbers in the real numbers. Every two distinct real numbers can be "separated" by a rational number that sits between them.

Comment: @RobertThingum It make sense "Every two distinct real numbers can be "separated" by a rational number that sits between them." +1